How to restore module in android studio
I uninstalled the module that should not have been deleted by mistake. What should I do to solve the problem caused by the uninstalled module? .gradle, build, and src folder turned red and I received an error message.
Project needs to be converted to androidx.*dependencies.
and
Code Insight is unavailable (script configuration wasn't received).
I tried to
disable/activate the options below in gradle.properties :
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false

or
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

and I deleted two lines above, but it didn't work.
There is no module now.
Project Structure>modules
I appreciate your help. I'm waiting for precious advice from experts!
